# Accessing files folder in Bolt CMS throws exception

Tags: bolt-cms

I made a fully functioning website with the Bolt CMS system on my home (development) system. After finishing and testing everything, I've put the site on the production webserver and it works like a charm, except for one thing: accessing, uploading and selecting files does not work. Furthermore, when I try to access the files section in the backend (`http://.../bolt/files`) I get the error:

```
Whoops\Exception\ErrorException thrown with message "syntax error, unexpected '['"

Stacktrace:
#0  in /home/etxean/domains/etxean.net/public_html/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:154
```

This is inside the `writeStream` function I checked file permissions and these are okay. Any idea where to look to debug this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lxg is correct in that this is being caused by a PHP 5.3/5.4 error.

To maintain compatibility with 5.3 we use a forked version of the Flysystem repo, but it seems that you are loading the real one.

I'm guessing this may be because you have installed Bolt as a composer package rather than downloading the distribution version.

If so then you can add the fork to your composer.json file in the root of your Bolt site. It should look like this:

```
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://github.com/rossriley/flysystem"
}],
```

then run a composer update and the Flysystem package will be replaced with the fork.

Comment: Thanks for the replies (Ross and lxg)! Your analysis was spot on. In fact, my development server has PHP 5.5.13 but the hosting server has 5.3.22 and therefore, it didn't show up until putting the site in production. 
The problem is that my provider does not allow shell access so I used composer on the dev site and then just FTPed everyting. Therefore, composer did not signal that my PHP version was < 5.4. 
I managed to solve it by setting the requirement for this component to `"league/flysystem": "0.5.3"`. Then it installs Ross's fork (even when my dev. PHP is > 5.4).

Comment: Next step is convincing my ISP to upgrade the PHP and give me shell acccess.... ;)

Answer (score 2):

[The file in question](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Filesystem.php) uses the PHP 5.4. array notation.

Prior to 5.4, an array would always be declared like

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Since PHP 5.4, you can use the JS(ON)/Python style array notation:

```
$foo = [1, 2, 3];
```

Solution: If you want to use this library, you should upgrade your server to at least PHP 5.4.

Theoretically, you could also modify the source file to run with PHP 5.3, but that would be a really bad idea in regard to maintainability.